# can SVELTE.js function code become a package or library?

Tags: javascript, html, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

so I create the component in svelte, and add to it custom logic,

 but compile it.

and then use native javascript to use the compiled version without doing the npm install of svelte.

---

basically, I want that the I can do something like this:

```js
function test(text) {
 // for example let's add with native JS this component
 document.body.innerHTML += `<MyCard myParameter="${text}">` // when calling myCard it will create also some other child components and so on...
 
 // or 
 myCardSvelteFunction(10, 12); // take some parameters, but this function came from svelte script compiled instead not javascript
}

test("foo bar");
```

```html
<script src="./mySvelteCompiled.js"></script>

<MyCard myParameter="hello world">
```

and this needs to not import svelte when development because technically we import the compiled version native javascript.

---

---

basically I have used a lot of javascript, and I very much liked the reusable code `function`s that you can make

by using `<script src="https://example.com/script.js>`

or `import/export` with `type="module"` attribute

---

in javascript is easy to write a function, copy the link of the script, call the function, and pass the parameters.

but since svelte is a compiled language I am wondering how can I make a function that can be used like it is a library

> class object-oriented code in particular
>
> this is because I have a very long vanilla js only code,
>
>  I want to refactor and rewrite better.

---

so I create the component in svelte, and add to it custom logic,

 but compile it.

and then use native javascript to use the compiled version without doing the npm install of svelte.

### is it possible?

---

want to know how the compiled code look like :

- go here and start writing: https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world?version=3.50.1
- click JS output
  [image]

> and it should in real time compile

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-custom-element-api

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're asking, but do checkout svelte's doc about [<script context="module">](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-context-module). I guess it's somewhat related.

Comment: And also custom element like @Corrl said. These 2 things are about integrating svelte's compiled code into vanilla JS codebase, __without__  re-compile with svelte compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's still experimental, you can use the official [`svelte-package`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/packaging) command to create a component library.

Comment: let's see maybe it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible. If I understand your question correctly, maybe passing the component `<MyCard/>` to another svelte component as a child using the `<slot/>` element could help. Like this: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/slots